# I get the error code 3154

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the error code "3154" when trying to restore files and filegroups. I searched for a suggestion, and it said to click on (with replace); still no go.

Full info:

> Restore failed for server "India/test. (Microsoft.sqlserver.smoextended)
>
> AM exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectuinInfo
>
> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than my existing "Test2" Database.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL server, error:3154)

Comment: Are you trying to restore a database that already exists? Why don't you drop it and restore the database? Or restore it with another name, it it's everything ok, drop the old one and rename the new. are you trying to do this task with the GUI or via code? you need to set the `move 'file' to 'file.mdf'` with the same name as the old database if you want to replace, or give it another name, to create a secondary one.

Comment: Try running `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` and `RESTORE HEADERONLY`, to get a better understanding of what's in the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use 'WITH REPLACE'

```
RESTORE DATABASE abc
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\abc_28082017.BAK'
WITH REPLACE
```